# For /F loop throwing "syntax of the command is incorrect"

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

Having issues for days now trying to figure this out, and hoping the community here can assist. Running the following command in a batch generates "the syntax of the command is incorrect", and I thinks its probably backquote placement, but I can't seem to figure out the right combo of quotes. Assistance would be greatly appreciated :)

```
FOR /F "USEBACKQ TOKENS=* DELIMS=" %%d IN (`"C:\PROGRAM FILES\7-Zip\7z.exe" l C:\TEST\FHNVPROV.XXX.0704.zip -slt ^| FINDSTR /s /i "\FHNVPROV\>"`) DO (SET "NAME=%%d")
```

I'm trying to use the For loop to launch 7-zip and read the contents of a .zip file (which only contains a text file of the same name "FHNVPROV.XXX.0704.txt"), find that .txt file name and output it to a variable.

Both commands work by themselves when run from a command line. I can even get them run piped correctly from a command line. And, depending on my experimentation with quote placement and usebackq, I've been able to get portions of the above to work, which is why I felt like that was my key here. Thanks all! :)

Comment: Have you tried replacing `\FHNVPROV\>` with `\FHNVPROV\^>`

Comment: @DennisvanGils, this won't change anything as the `>` is in between a pair of `"`; however, I guess the OP intended to use `"\<FHNVPROV\>"`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before I tell you what is wrong here, I assume you intended to use the regular expression `\<FHNVPROV\>` (there is the `<` missing in your question; I also put the ZIP file path in `""` here):

```
FOR /F "USEBACKQ TOKENS=* DELIMS=" %%d IN (`"C:\PROGRAM FILES\7-Zip\7z.exe" l "C:\TEST\FHNVPROV.XXX.0704.zip" -slt ^| FINDSTR /s /i "\<FHNVPROV\>"`) DO (SET "NAME=%%d")
```

---

The problem is that the expression within the set of the `for /F` loop (that is the parsed part within parentheses) looks enclosed within `""` to the `for /F` command (even though it is already enclosed within ``` `` ```), because the first and last characters in between the backticks are `"` both. The `for /F` command seems to remove the backticks and also the first and the last quotation marks and executes the remainder, which is: `C:\PROGRAM FILES\7-Zip\7z.exe" l "C:\TEST\FHNVPROV.XXX.0704.zip" -slt ^| FINDSTR /s /i "\<FHNVPROV\>`. This is of course an invalid command line and therefore a syntax error arises.

To work around this issue, you have got the following options:

1. to avoid the first or the last character to be a quotation mark; in the following example I used the short name of the directory `C:\Program Files` (type `dir /X "C:\Program Files*"` in command prompt to find out; I used `C:\PROGRA~1` here), so it does not contain white-spaces and hence no `""` are required any more:

   ```
    FOR /F "USEBACKQ TOKENS=* DELIMS=" %%d IN (`C:\PROGRA~1\7-Zip\7z.exe l "C:\TEST\FHNVPROV.XXX.0704.zip" -slt ^| FINDSTR /s /i "\<FHNVPROV\>"`) DO (SET "NAME=%%d")
   ```
2. to place another pair of quotation marks around the entire expression; the `for /F` command removes the ``` `` ``` and the outermost `""`, so the remainder is a valid command line; however, the command interpreter will now detect the `<` and `>` characters in the regular expression to be outside of a quoted string, so you need to escape them; the `|` however is seen as part of a quoted string, so no escaping is necessary, although it would not harm; to understand that, you need to read the line from left to right character by character, and to imagine a sort of "quoted" flag, which is toggled as soon as you encounter a `"`, and which disables recognition of special characters when set (see also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133)):

   ```
    FOR /F "USEBACKQ TOKENS=* DELIMS=" %%d IN (`""C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" l "C:\TEST\FHNVPROV.XXX.0704.zip" -slt | FINDSTR /s /i "\^<FHNVPROV\^>""`) DO (SET "NAME=%%d")
   ```

***EDIT*** - You can avoid restructuring the command by escaping the outer quotes instead:

```
FOR /F "USEBACKQ TOKENS=* DELIMS=" %%d IN (`^""C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" l "C:\TEST\FHNVPROV.XXX.0704.zip" -slt ^| FINDSTR /s /i "\<FHNVPROV\>"^"`) DO (SET "NAME=%%d")
```

Comment: I tried to suggest the escaped quotes in a comment, but the backslashes messed up the in-line code syntax. So I decided to edit your answer instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @dbenham! If you had posted your own answer, I would definitely have upvoted it as this is the most convenient solution...

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the assistance and the awesome explanations! Learned a thing or two today :) Greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome! please consider to accept the answer in case it helped you and fully addressed the issue of your question...